# Filter ListView data with CheckBox inputs

Tags: vb.net, listview, filter

I'm trying to provide a way to filter data within a `ListView` using `CheckBox` controls. Checking a box will add or remove the selected attribute from the `ListView`.

The current code:

```
For i = 0 To RecCount
    Filter = True

    'RecordDat array populated here

    'filter the record by checkbox selection

    If ckbComplete.Checked = True And Len(RecordDat(7)) = 0 Then
        Filter = False
    ElseIf ckbOpen.Checked = True And Len(RecordDat(7)) > 0 Then
        Filter = false
    ElseIf ckbApps.Checked = True And strings.Left(RecordDat(0).ToString, 4) <> "APPS" Then
        Filter = False
    ElseIf ckbContract.Checked = True And Strings.Left(RecordDat(0), 3) <> "SOP" Then
        Filter = false
    End If

    If Filter = False Then GoTo SkipItem
    ' More code adding the item to the list view and formatting

SkipItem:
    Next
```

At the moment I can filter only once per array index, i.e. I can filter `ckbComplete` and `ckbApps` but not `ckbcomplete, ckbApps` and `ckbContract`.

Comment: Suggestion: Instead of `GoTo` try using `Continue For` instead.

Comment: @AllenBinuya - thanks! I've been looking for a more rounded way of skipping code.

Comment: I just did what I have to do because legend says _"GoTo is evil"_ if misused.

Comment: That aside, what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I have a ListView full of data - I want users to be able to filter what they see depending by checking one or several checkboxes. For example, a user may want to see open jobs in applications therefore he checks `ckbopen` and `ckbApps`. Selecting this plus `ckbContract` i.e. open applications and contract jobs, yields an empty ListView.

Comment: Describe the issue. It would also be helpful to add where your data is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure out a solution by trial and error and wish to share what I found.

In order to filter the data, each variable (in this case, the column value) required its own filter statements, each which must be encased in an `If ELSE` statement.

The resulting code was as follows:

```
Dim Filter As Boolean = True
        For i = 0 To RecCount
            Filter = False

'RecordDat initialisation               

            Filter = FilterPass(RecordDat)
            If Filter = False Then Continue For

            Dim itm As ListViewItem
            itm = New ListViewItem(RecordDat)
            Healthchart.ListView1.Items.Add(itm)

'Continue formatting and input of data into listview


        Next
```

The `FilterPass` functions then follow:

```
Private Function FilterPass(ByVal RecordDat() As String)
    Dim filter As Boolean = False
    If Healthchart.ckbComplete.Checked = True Then
        If Len(RecordDat(7)) > 0 Then
            filter = FilterPass2(RecordDat)
            If filter = True Then
                filter = FilterPass3(RecordDat)
            End If
        End If
    End If

    If Healthchart.ckbOpen.Checked = True Then
        If Len(RecordDat(7)) = 0 Then
            filter = FilterPass2(RecordDat)
            If filter = True Then
                filter = FilterPass3(RecordDat)
            End If
        End If
    End If
    Return filter
End Function


Private Function FilterPass2(ByVal RecordDat() As String)
    Dim filter As Boolean = False
    If Healthchart.ckbApps.Checked = True Then
        If Strings.Left(RecordDat(0).ToString, 4) = "APPS" Then
            filter = True
        End If
    End If
    If Healthchart.ckbContract.Checked = True Then
        If Strings.Left(RecordDat(0), 3) = "SOP" Then
            filter = True
        End If
    End If
    If Healthchart.ckbTech.Checked = True Then
        If Strings.Left(RecordDat(0), 3) = "ATS" Then
            filter = True
        End If
    End If
    If Healthchart.ckbDes.Checked = True Then
        If Strings.Left(RecordDat(0), 3) = "DES" Then
            filter = True
        End If
    End If
    Return filter
End Function

Private Function FilterPass3(ByVal RecordDat() As String)
    Dim filter As Boolean = True
    Dim SubDate As Date = Date.ParseExact(RecordDat(1).ToString, "dd/MM/yy", System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)

    If Healthchart.ckbLast30.Checked = True Then
        If DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -30, Now) > SubDate Then
            filter = False
        End If
    End If
    If Healthchart.ckb7Days.Checked = True Then
        If DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -7, Now) > SubDate Then
            filter = False
        End If
    End If
    Return filter
End Function
```

One can then add as many 'filters' as required by adding an additional `If Filter = true then` into the `FilterPass` function.